# Kaprekar Process and Palindromes.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion, palindrome

Based from what I understand, a positive integer $n$ is said to be Kaprekar if it goes back to itself after employing Kaprekar's Routine given below:

1. Arrange the digits in descending and then in ascending order.
2. Subtract the smaller number from the bigger number.
3. Back at 1. and continue the process till we get $n$.

Example: 495 is a Kaprekar Number since $954-459=495$.

I noticed from this point that a palindrome of odd number of digits is not Kaprekar.

Example: Consider 272, by applying Kaprekar Routine we have: $722-227=495$ and surely after getting 495, we cant go back to 272. Thus 272 is not Kaprekar.

As a question, Is my observation always TRUE? How can I show it in general?

Thanks for your valuable comments and answers in advance.

Comment: I will write a proof for this by tomorrow (Or give a counterexample). Give me some time; I've have an exam tomorrow.

Comment: @Kugelblitz Thanks, will wait for your answer and God bless on your exam.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, it means a lot to me.

Comment: @JrAntalan I have posted all the solutions for you.

My final year project is on the Kaprekar routine and after seeing this question I decided to find out the answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the definition of a Kaprekar number is different from what you've understood sir... : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar_number

You wish to say 'Kaprekar's constants' arising out of the Kaprekar's routine.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6174_(number)

I will update my post tomorrow after finding a proof/ counterexample for the conjecture you've made regarding the Kaprekar constants.

Edit: The Kaprekar Constant for three digit numbers seems to be 495 as evidenced by this, and palindromic numbers don't seem to be there...:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/KaprekarRoutineFlowGraph495.svg/1500px-KaprekarRoutineFlowGraph495.svg.png

So tomorrow I can surely come up with a formal proof. Good night or good day to you sir.

---

*Edit: Alright. This is regarding the Kaprekar's constant. Kaprekar's number is something else entirely.*

**It seems that for the set of numbers containing 3 digits, 495 is the constant; that is, most numbers resolve to the number 495, except the following numbers**

```
100, 101, 110, 111, 112, 121, 122, 211, 212, 221, 222, 223, 232, 233, 322, 323, 332, 333, 334, 343, 344, 433, 434, 443, 444, 445, 454, 455, 544, 545, 554, 555, 556, 565, 566, 655, 656, 665, 666, 667, 676, 677, 766, 767, 776, 777, 778, 787, 788, 877, 878
```

*http://oeis.org/A090429 : This gives you the list for 3-digit numbers that do not resolve to 495 under the Kaprekar routine which I've copy pasted.*

So we can conclude, that the only three digit number which results in itself after the Kaprekar Routine is 459. There is nothing to do with odd digit palindromes; from 100 to 999, only 459 follows the routine (i.e. not only do all 3-digit palindromes follow the routine to return to itself, no other number can do so).

With reference to five digit numbers, {(53955, 59994), (61974, 82962, 75933, 63954), (62964, 71973, 83952, 74943)} are possible cycles a number may end up in. So it's a collection of cycling constants in case of a five digit number.

For further amount of digits....not much research has been done yet.

**Basically, there's no need for a proof as such for the three digit palindromes, because only 495 is the number which can come back to itself after the Routine *(All three digit non-palindromes also do not follow the routine; they also end up in 495 like the palindromes, which then follows the routine)*.**

But yes, one conjecture that can be made here, is that all non-repetitive odd digit palindromes (i.e. All digits are not equal to each and every other) eventually result in a Kaprekar constant, or a Kaprekar's cycling constants.

Comment: thank you again. Yeah that must be constant.

Comment: @JrAntalan I've updated my answer.

Comment: I will wait for your proof, thanks

Comment: @JrAntalan I've updated, but the answer isn't what I thought it would be :( Looks like there are no Kaprekar's constants besides 495 at all for 3 digit numbers!

Comment: I think we already have a proof. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

All palindromic fixed points:

$1001_2, 10101_2, 101101_2, 1011101_2, 10111101_2, 101111101_2, \dots$

$101101_2, 213312_4, 325523_6, 437734_8,549945, \dots$

There are no other palindromic Kaprekar Palindromes.